# Will this optimisation give the global maximum?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

My book optimises a type of functions using the lagrange method. From calculus I remember that we had to check the boundary when using lagrange, because it only gave local max, but it is not mentioned in the book. I see from this link http://planetmath.org/localminimumofconvexfunctionisnecessarilyglobal that it might be global after all since we are using a concave function. But since the probelm is more involved than a single variable, and we use Lagrange I am not sure it will work.

We want to maximize

$F(\textbf{x})=\Sigma_{i=1}^nk_i*u(x_i)$,

$k_i$ is a real number

$F: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

constrained to:

$g(\textbf{x})=c, g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, g is always linear and on the form: $g(\textbf{x})=\Sigma_{i=1}^nt_i*x_i$

It is also mentioned that **u is concave**, and strictly increasing.

Now, **when we use Lagrange method on this problem and find a local max, will it infact then be a global max?** The book never checks if the value found using lagrange is maximum. I mean we have found a local max using Lagrange on the set we are constrained to, but does infact in some way that the function u is concave ensure that the value is a global max?

PS: This problem is from mathematical finance(portfolio-optimisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we use Lagrange method on [*a linear combination of concave functions constrained to a linear space*] and find a local max, will it in fact then be a global max?

Yes:

A linear combination of concave functions is also concave.

A concave function restricted to a linear space (e.g. the hyperplane $g = c$) is concave.

A local maximum of a concave function is a global maximum.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by higher dimensional linear space? I get these two from google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_%28geometry%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space. Or do you mean planes when we get in higher dimensions?

Comment: An [affine subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is what I had in mind --- like a vector subspace, but possibly translated. You have a hyperplane (i.e. dimension $n-1$ affine subspace) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as your constraint space $g = c$.